# Homogeneous analytic function on Banach space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a complex Banach space. We say $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic if it satisfies the following:

1.$f$ is locally bounded. That means given $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f$ is bounded on $U$;

2.For all $x,y\in X$, the function $\lambda \mapsto f(x+\lambda y)$ is holomorphic for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Remark: the continuity of $f$ can be deduced from Schwarz lemma and 1. If $X$ is finite dimensional, 1 can be omitted.

---

**Problem**: Let $X$ be a complex Banach space, $m$ is a positive integer. Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on $X$ , such that $$f(\lambda x)=\lambda ^m f(x)$$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove there exists a continuous m-linear functional $\phi: X^m \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, such that $f=\phi \circ \Delta$ where $\Delta: X\rightarrow X^m$ is the diagonal map.

---

**My observation**:

1.If $X$ is finite-dimensional, namely $\mathbb{C}^n$, the definition of holomorphic function on $X$ is coincide with the definition of ordinary several varieties holomorphic function, and the claim is true by Taylor expansion.

2.For the case $m=1$, let $x,y \in X$, consider $g: (\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \mapsto f(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y)$ which is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is 1-homogeneous, so $g(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2$. Put $\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=0$ we see $a=f(x)$, similarly $b=f(y)$. Then put $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, we see $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Thus $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $X$.

3.For the case $m\neq 1$, I tried to consider $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_m)\mapsto f(\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j x_j)$ but it has some difficult to make sure the coefficients.

4.Maybe we can consider tensor product of $X$, to reduce the $m$-case to $1$-case.

---

Any hint or references? Thank you!