Nonlinear homogeneous map $f : \Bbb{C} \times \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$
I am looking for an example of a map $f : \Bbb{C} \times \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ which satisfies the following properties:

$f$ is continuous,
$f$ is homogeneous, i.e. $f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda f(x,y)$ for all $\lambda, x, y \in \Bbb{C}$,
$f(x,0) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{C}$,
$f(0,y) = y$ for all $y \in \Bbb{C}$.

Obviously, $f(x,y) = y$ is a trivial example of such a map. I'm interested whether this is the only example. Such a nontrivial example clearly cannot be a linear map.
My attempts:
The best thing I could come up with was this rational function:
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}, &\quad \text{ if }(x,y) \ne (0,0),\\
0, &\quad \text{ if }(x,y) = (0,0).
\end{cases}$$
It seems that this would work as a map $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, but is clearly undefined for $x = \pm iy$ when considered as a map $\Bbb{C} \times \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$.
Another attempt would be this simple function:
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
y, &\quad \text{ if }x \ne 0,\\
0, &\quad \text{ if }x = 0.
\end{cases}$$
However this is not continuous at $(0,y)$ for nonzero $y$.

@SassatelliGiulio Of couse, thank you.

Rational functions $\frac{p}{q}$ with both $p,q$ homogenous polynominals and $\deg p=\deg q+1$ are out of the equation since your denominator will always have a root by the fundamental theorem of algebra, unless $q=const$. And that leaves you with the example you have just found, $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{1}$.

Unless I'm mistaken, and unlike for real variables, the assumptions $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply that $f$ is separately holomorphic and thus by the Hartogs theorem that $f$ is jointly holomorphic, which gives the continuity for free and also should heavily restrict the form of $f$, as homogeneous holomorphic functions are probably very special. I found this (unanswered) question on the subject for example, and it seems like an exercise given to OP so there might be an answer somewhere: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4114611/1104384

@BrunoB Good point, I was also thinking that $f(x,y)=y$ might be the only solution to this problem. Iirc, all homogenous entire functions must be polynomials, but I couldn't connect all the dots safely enough to answer. In particular, I am not sure about the holomorphic requirement being fullfilled.

@F.Conrad Nevermind to apply Hartogs you would need all the $x \mapsto f(x,y_0)$ and $y \mapsto f(x,y_0)$, but maybe you can do something with homogeneity? Sorry I am not too familiar with functions of several complex variables.

@BrunoB Yeah, indeed if you assume that $f$ is holomorphic, then by that exercise we get that $f(x,y) = y$ is the only solution. However, my second example satisfies all properties but is not even continuous, let alone holomorphic.

@F.Conrad I was thinking of a rational function extended by some value, for example $0$, at the zeroes of $q$. But also I have no reason to assume that $f$ couldn't take some kind of wild form.

But then you would violate the continuity assumption, wouldnt you?

@F.Conrad I'm not so sure, my first example is continuous (although maybe this is indeed impossible in $\Bbb{C} \times \Bbb{C}$).

Yeah, $f(x,y)=y$ is. But I am starting to think this is the only solution. Maybe something like Eulers homogeneity theorem (deducing a PDE) might work and then show uniqueness for this problem, but that seems like a longshot.

Consider an arbitrary continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb C$ st $g(0)=0, g(z)=z, |z| \ge 1, |g(z)| \le |z|$ but $g$ is not the identity.
(eg take $g(re^{it})=r^2e^{it}, r \le 1, g(z)=z, |z| \ge 1$)
Then I claim that $f(x,y)=xg(y/x), x \ne 0, f(0,y)=y$  satisfies the required properties. Clearly $f(x,0)=0, f(0,y)=y$ and $f(\lambda x, \lambda y)= \lambda f(x,y)$ so we need to show continuity only and that is obvious at any $(x,y), x \ne 0$
But if we let $(x_n, y_n) \to (0, y)$ we have $|f(x_n, y_n)| = |x_n||g(y_n/x_n)| \le |y_n|$ if $x_n \ne 0$ by our assumption that $|g(z)| \le |z|$ while $f(0, y_n)=y_n$ obviously satisfies same so in particular if $y=0$ so $y_n \to 0$ we have $f(x_n, y_n) \to 0$ hence the function is continuous at $(0,0)$
Now if $y \ne 0$ then wlog we can assume $x_n \ne 0$ as otherwise result is clear and then since $|y_n| \ge |y|/2$ for large enough $n$ we have $|y_n/x_n| \ge 1, n \ge n_0$ so $g(y_n/x_n)=y_n/x_n$ there so $f(x_n, y_n)=y_n \to y=f(0,y)$ and $f$ is continuous there too.

Amazing, thank you very much, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Do you perhaps happen to know if $f$ is necessarily of this form?

If you consider $g(z)=f(1,z)$ you get indeed a $g$ and I think you can prove that $g$ is close to the identity for large enough $|z|$ but not sure that you can prove that $g$ must be the identity for large $z$
